# Clojure: Update value of record field

Tags: clojure

I have defined record to store User details and Address Details.

```
(defrecord User [id name address])

(defrecord Address [id location street city state])

(def usr (User. 1 "Abc"
           (Address. 1 "Location 1" "Street" "NY" "US")))
```

I have updated "name" to "BCD" using the below code

```
(assoc usr :name "BCD")
```

**Output:**

```
#async_tea_party.core.User{:id 1, :name "BCD", :address #async_tea_party.core.Address{:id 1, :location "Location 1", :street "Street", :city "NY", :state "US"}}
```

(usr)

**OutPut:**

```
#async_tea_party.core.User{:id 1, :name "Abc", :address #async_tea_party.core.Address{:id 1, :location "Location 1", :street "Street", :city "NY", :state "US"}}
```

New value of `name` field has not updated and It still shows old value.

How can I update "name" field permanently in "User" record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(def usr (User...))` is kind of immutable. You cannot change it.
When you do `(assoc usr :name "BCD")` you are not changing it. You create a new one. In order to do what you want you need an atom.

```
(def usr (atom (User. 1 "Abc"
           (Address. 1 "Location 1" "Street" "NY" "US"))))

(:name @usr) ;; "Abc"
(swap! usr assoc :name "BCD")
(:name @usr) ;; "BCD"
```

Comment: @user1702169 This work. But most likely, you need to structure your program to avoid relying on atom, and pass the new record where you need it directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is called immutability and is one of the main reasons for me to like clojure so much.

To understand the reasoning why this behaviour is so beneficial, reading [values and state](https://clojure.org/about/state) really helped me