# How to update fields of a Clojure record

Tags: clojure

I have this record:

```clj
(defrecord Point [x y z])
(def location (Point. 1 2 3))
```

Now I want to create a new variable `new-location` based on `location`, but with the `z` coordinate changed. I know that I could manually copy all the fields i.e. `(def new-location (Point. (:x location) (:y location) 99))`, but is there a simpler way to functionally update only a few fields of a Clojure record?

Note that I am looking for an immutable solution. [Clojure: Update value of record field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165525/clojure-update-value-of-record-field) is about mutation, and therefore does not answer my question.

Comment: I think `assoc` works with records as well as maps.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Thank you. Perhaps you could write that as an answer. `(def new-location (assoc location :z 99))` solves the problem.

Comment: I don’t try writing answers from my phone and I won’t be at a computer anytime soon. But Alan provided a nice answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `assoc`:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defrecord Point [x y z])
(dotest
  (newline)
  (def p1 (->Point 1 2 3))
  (spyx p1)
  (spyx (type p1))

  (newline)
  (def p2 (assoc p1 :z 99))
  (spyx p2)
  (spyx (type p2))

  (newline)
  (def m2 (into {} p1 ))
  (spyx m2)
  (spyx (type m2))

  (newline)
  (def m3 (dissoc p1 :z ))
  (spyx m3)
  (spyx (type m3))

  (newline)
  (def m4 (assoc p1 :extra 42 ))
  (spyx m4)
  (spyx (type m4))

)
```

with result

```clj
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

p1 => #tst.demo.core.Point{:x 1, :y 2, :z 3}
(type p1) => tst.demo.core.Point

p2 => #tst.demo.core.Point{:x 1, :y 2, :z 99}
(type p2) => tst.demo.core.Point

m2 => {:x 1, :y 2, :z 3}
(type m2) => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

m3 => {:x 1, :y 2}
(type m3) => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

m4 => #tst.demo.core.Point{:x 1, :y 2, :z 3, :extra 42}
(type m4) => tst.demo.core.Point
```

Note that a simple `assoc` preserves the result as a record of the same type.  Some operations create a map result, as we see with `dissoc` creating `m3`.

However, using `assoc` to add an `:extra` field to create `m4` preserves the type as a `Point` record. Surprise, surprise!

Build from [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: "Other operations create a map result" - Well, some operations, anyway. Anything that builds a new map from scratch (e.g. `into {}`) will of course create an ordinary map. But anything like `conj` and `update` which alter an existing structure will preserve the record.

Comment: I clarified the text. `m3` is a map as I expected, but I was surprised that `m4` remained a record.

Comment: 'dissoc' downgrades to a map only when removing a basis field.  For example, `(dissoc m4 :extra)` yields a Point.

Comment: What is `spyx`? It appears to be from a third-party library.

Comment: If you clone the template project, you can execute `lein test` as is, then add code and see the result.